# opening port on router for apache server

Tags: port

I'd like to access my Ubuntu headless box from outside world.

I'm trying to do port forwarding and I think something is going wrong...

I've d-link DSL-2640B

Advanced -> Port Forwarding

serverName: Web Server (HTTP)

External port start: 8891

External port end: 8891

TCP

Internal port start: 8891

Internal port end: 8891

Server IP: 192.168.1.99

Remote IP Addres: ???????

nboundFilter: Allow All

wan interface: ppp0_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone who has same problem... There was no problem.

I was trying to access my server apache from within WAN with publicIp:port

I simply tried to browse from different internet network and I got routed correctly to server with publicIp:port.

Now why is this so is subject of another question :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your apache server running on port 80 or 8891? The default apache setup for ubuntu sets it up to listen on port 80, which means you need to forward port 80 on your router instead of 8891.

If you specifically only want to use that port (8891), then you need to go into your /etc/apache2/ports.conf file and change "Listen 80" to "Listen 8891" and then restart the server.

Comment: my apache is running on port 8891.